# I need 1000 Ethereum wallets for load testing of my project, is there a way i can get that?

Tags: wallets, testing, defi, staking

I have to test out the functionality of auto reinvest in my smart contract in staking, therefore I need about 1000 Ethereum wallets to test out my code!

Please help me out here if there is any possible way!

Comment: wouldn't a fuzzy test work ?

Comment: I presume you're in testnet (asking for 1.000 real ETH is a bit nonsense). You can publish your testnet address and ask for community members to donate from faucet. Or you can start a Ganache and give you all money you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hardhat local deployment for testing . Run npx hardhat node on your terminal and it will give you addresses and its private key